# I need to transfer videos from my iPhone 6 to my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone

I want to be able to transfer some videos from my iPhone to my Mac so that I can create a YouTube video. The problem is that I can't insert a cable into my Mac because it only has inserts for a charger and headphones. Is there any way I can email or use Dropbox to get the pictures and videos into my Mac?

Comment: Have you tried Airdrop?

Comment: To be able to help you, it'd be good to know your exact model of Mac and what OS you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I assume that you're talking about [MacBook](http://www.apple.com/au/macbook/specs/) what only has only one USB-C port.

For transferring media from your iPhone to your MacBook you have multiple options:

- Use AirDrop
- Use [Lighting to USB-C cable](http://www.apple.com/au/shop/product/MK0X2AM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-cable-1m)
- Use iCloud or any other cloud provider (Dropbox, Google Drive or Dropbox)